# FullCalendar Month View displaying events on weekend

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have an event that includes part or all of a weekend.  I am displaying the calendar in Month View. However, I can span an event over mulitple days during the week just fine.

I am using the following scripts:

- jquery-1.8.0.min.js:
- jquery-ui-1.8.23.min.js:
- fullcalendar.min.js

My calendar is set as:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    defaultView: "month",
    firstDay: 7,
    weekends: true,
    events: Controller/GetEvents
});
```

Event data that errors (weekend) is set as:

```
id: 1
title: "Kat's Test Event"
allDay: true
start: 1348902000
end: 1348988400
url: myUrl
editable: false
```

This throws an `"Invalid argument"` error in fullcalendar.min.js on this line:

```
n[0].style.top = C[B.row] + (B.top || 0) + "px"
```

From what I can tell, B.top = -Infinity.

Event data that works (week) is set as:

```
id: 1
title: "Kat's Test Event"
allDay: true
start: 1348556400
end: 1348729200
url: myUrl
editable: false
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?